# Add SelectionListener to SWT Browser

Tags: java, swt, listener, eclipse-rap

I'm implementing a ad-section in my RAP application (1.5M7). To show the ads, I used [SWT Browser](http://git.eclipse.org/c/rap/org.eclipse.rap.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.rwt/src/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.java?id=7302fa89b4e433f1d3d9f7934ce338e552966eee). How can I detect user-clicks on the browser (the ad) to be able to forward him to a linked page?

Comment: Is it a simple text ad or flash media?? Are you showing some remote web-page or just populating the browser with your custom html `(using browser.setText())`??It would be good if you can share some more insights about the html (ad) content.

Comment: @Favonius: The contents are GIF's and Flash. As I will use an ad-server later, I call browser.setUrl() to show the content. So it will rather be a web-page than a custom HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the html from an external server, you will not be able to get the click for security reasons. You will have to create a html-document (as a string) that loads the gif/flash object directly (not using an iframe), and set that document using setText. Then you can get the click using a BrowserFunction instance. For a gif this is simple: `<img src="your_ad.gif" onclick="your_browser_function();">`. I do not know how to get a click from a flash object.